Relation between Christoffel Symbols and metric tensor
I am learning about Riemannian geometry, and I have a question about relation between the Christoffel symbols and the metric tensor of the manifold. Is it true that the Christoffel symbols are unique for each metric tensor and it depends only on the given metric tensor ?
I hope someone will enlight me with the interesting ideas. Thanks.

This website has a very nice compilation of formulas for the Christoffel symbols in terms of the metric tensor. https://www.akalin.com/curvature-moving-frames

I suggest focusing on learning what the Levi-Civita connection (i.e., covariant differentiation) is. Christoffel symbols appear when you want to describe the Levi-Civita connection with respect to coordinates.

Christoffel symbols depend on the connection AND a choice of local coordinates (or slightly more generally, a local frame of vector fields).
So in (semi-)Riemannian geometry, where we almost always use the Levi-Civita connection, the Christoffel symbols depend only on the metric and a choice of local frame of vector fields (most commonly coordinate vector fields).

Is this a major result in Riemannian geometry, and how can one give a proof of it ?

Google Levi civita connection and its local formula (or look at the link in the comments).

Also, the Christoffel symbols may be zero in a choice of coordinates and nonzero in another. This is unlike matrices.

@PermQi, are you taking a course or reading a book? How the Christoffel symbols arise from the metric tensor is covered in any standard course or textbook on Riemannian geometry.

I am not sure why the other responders didn't include the simple explicit formula for the $\Gamma$ symbols in terms of the metric, so I will: $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{g^{\ell k}}{2} \big(g_{i\ell,j}-g_{ij,\ell}+g_{j\ell,i}\big)$, where the comma stands for the corresponding partial derivative, with implied summation over the index $\ell$.
